# cannot assign 'torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential' as parameter

Tags: pytorch

I was following this method
(https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dynamic-parameter-declaration-in-forward-function/427) to dynamically assign parameters in `forward` function.

However, my parameter is not just one single weight tensor but it is `nn.Sequential`.

When I implement below:

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        # you need to register the parameter names earlier
        self.register_parameter('W_di', None)

    def forward(self, input):
        if self.W_di is None:
            self.W_di = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(mL_n * 2, 1024),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(1024, self.hS)).to(device)
```

I get the following error.

```
 TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential' as parameter 'W_di' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

Is there any way that I can register `nn.Sequential` as a whole param? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you or other users still have this problem, one solution to consider is using `nn.ModuleList` instead of `nn.Sequential`.

While `nn.Sequential` is useful for defining a fixed sequence of layers in PyTorch, `nn.ModuleList` is a more flexible container that allows direct access and modification of individual layers within the list. This can be especially helpful when dealing with dynamic models or architectures that require more complex layer arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that you cannot do it. Even in the static model declaration, `nn.Module` also specifies the parameters of every sub-modules (e.g., `nn.Conv2d` or `nn.Linear`) in a nested way. That is, every kernel or bias is registered one by one and independently.

One workaround might be to introduce dynamic sub-modules. Here is my brief implementation. One can define desired dynamic behaviors inside the function `DynamicLinear`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class DynamicLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DynamicLinear, self).__init__()
        # you need to register the parameter names earlier
        self.register_parameter('W_di', None)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.W_di is None:
            # dynamically define a linear function here
            self.W_di = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1, 1)).to(x.device)
        return self.W_di @ x

class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
                    DynamicLinear(),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    DynamicLinear())

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)


m = MyModule()

x = torch.ones(1, 1)
y = m(x)
# output: 1
print(y)
```